# How do you return a specific field from Sphinx results?

Tags: text, indexing, sphinx

Assume I'm indexing a table of books. They have title, author, description, etc.

I want to do a search across all fields and return the title of the books that contain my search term. I can do a search and return the book_id (doc_id) from Sphinx so I can look them up myself, but what would be really awesome is if Sphinx just gave me the titles so I don't have to hit the database at all. I can get Sphinx to return different attributes to me, but getting a text field is eluding me.

Is this possible? If so, how do you do it?

[Update] Found this today: http://www.sphinxsearch.com/faq.html#row-storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to kill the idea so quickly, but it's not possible. Sphinx doesn't return any information about the values of fields, nor even which fields provided a match on the query.

And to elaborate a little more... Sphinx usually loads *all* attribute values into memory, which is probably why it's fine with returning them for each result. It could be that fields are stored in a non-reversible encoding, and so can't be translated back to normal values? That's a stab in the dark, though.

Answer (score 3):

There some trick is. As I answer [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11984803/1057209), you could add these column you wanna get to the **attr** entries, then you could just pick the value from the result from sphinx.

May it be helpful for you :D

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a small amount of data in text fields then you can use Sphinx string attributes.

```
sql_attr_string
```

But, it have some limitation like:

> String attributes can store arbitrary strings attached to every
>   document. There's a fixed size limit of 4 MB per value. Also, searchd
>   will currently cache all the values in RAM, which is an additional
>   implicit limit.

So, it would be not good idea to store a lot of data in them, because all attributes are stored in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

There's been some progress on this front. Now, if you use [SphinxSE](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxse), you can join the SphinxSE table which you search on to the table the index was generated on, and get your title's that way.