# how to get all column value from sphinx by configuration file php

Tags: php, sphinx

i want to know how to get all column value from table using sphinx search...

i have configuration file, that file can get only one field from table.

but i need all field value.

where will i modify for getting all field from table.

thanks and advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sphinx will only return the document id, weight and attributes. Use MySQL to get the rest of the values.

1. Do a Sphinx search, which will give you a list of document IDs
2. For every document ID, do a MySQL query which gives you the values for all fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some tricks could be used for the problem.

1. if the column is not included in fulltext search, you could add it into **attr** entry. e.g. for field name and age, in xmlpipe2 source config file, you could add these in the `index` part:

   ```
   xmlpipe_attr_string = name
   xmlpipe_attr_uint = age
   ```
2. if the column is included in fulltext search, you could add it into **attr** entry and **field** entry the same time. e.g. for field intro, in xmlpipe2 source config file, you could add these in the **index** part:

   ```
   xmlpipe_field = intro
   xmlpipe_attr_string = intro
   ```